# How to solve "call to undefined function domxml_new_doc()...."

Tags: php, xml, mxml

I am trying to output xml by using domxml_new_doc.

However, I just got the call to undefined function domxml_new_doc() error.
I tried google it but still not luck. Do I have to install any extension or 
library? Thanks for the help.

```
 $doc=domxml_new_doc("1.0"); //error on this line....
$node=$doc->create_element("marker");
$parnode=$doc->append_child($node);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see the requirements [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domxml.requirements.php). Quote:

> This extension makes use of the » GNOME XML library. Download and install this library. You will need at least libxml-2.4.14. To use DOM XSLT features you can use the » libxslt library and EXSLT enhancements from » http://www.exslt.org/. Download and install these libraries if you plan to use (enhanced) XSLT features. You will need at least libxslt-1.0.18.

Comment: The website's downloaded page is a xmlsoft.org server with so many files..Would you tell me which one I should download it? Thanks...

Comment: i don't know whats your servers OS... but if its any kind of linux, i think "libxml2-2.7.7.tar.gz" sounds good. maybe its also possible to install libxml/libxslt by using yast on your terminal...

Comment: ty. I just found out ibxml2-2.7.7.tar.gz is what I need..I say its a very poor organized website...Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

What PHP version are you using? You need to ensure that make sure you have the domxml library/extension.