# Call to undefined function domxml_new_doc()

Tags: php, xml, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to solve “call to undefined function domxml_new_doc()…”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006246/how-to-solve-call-to-undefined-function-domxml-new-doc)

I'm using php5, when I  try initializing a `domxml_new_doc()` it gives following error

```
Call to undefined function domxml_new_doc()
```

I checked phpinfo and found that DOM/XML is enabled...

Here is the code line which gives me the error

```
$doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
```

Comment: There are two extension "DOMDocument" and "DOM XML (PHP4)" ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php ). You are sure you enabled the right one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006246/how-to-solve-call-to-undefined-function-domxml-new-doc check this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by KingCrunch, you're likely to be using PHP5. In that case, just use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

However if you're still using PHP4, then the following test will tell you whether the extension is loaded:

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('domxml'));
```

If it returns false, then you have to enable the domxml library.
If you can modify php.ini, then locate a line `extension=domxml.so` (unix) or `extension=domxml.dll` (windows), uncomment it, then restart the web server.

If you cannot find this line, then you may have to install this library, which is outside the scope of this question :)